# plotting count of zeros and ones in a dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

I have a dataframe like this:

```
    Name        Detection
0   name1           0
1   name2           0
2   name3           0
3   name1           1
4   name3           1
5   name2           1
6   name1           1
7   name1           0
```

I want a bar plot that shows the count of 0's and 1's on the y-axis, separately, based on each name on the x-axis, something like this:

[image]

How can I do that?

Comment: `from matplotlib import pyplot;df.groupby('Name')['Detection'].count().plot(kind='bar')`

Comment: @Manakin I tried this but I want to separate the count of zero's and one's with different colors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this runnable code:

```
import pandas as pd
from io import StringIO
from matplotlib import pyplot

data2 ="""Index     Name        Detection
0   name1           0
1   name2           0
2   name3           0
3   name1           1
4   name3           1
5   name2           1
6   name1           1
7   name1           0"""

df2 = pd.read_csv(StringIO( data2 ), sep='\s+', index_col='Index', engine='python')
print(df2)
result = df2.groupby(['Name']).count()
print()
print(result)

result.plot(kind='bar')
```

Output text:

```
        Name  Detection
Index                  
0      name1          0
1      name2          0
2      name3          0
3      name1          1
4      name3          1
5      name2          1
6      name1          1
7      name1          0

       Detection
Name            
name1          4
name2          2
name3          2
```

Output plot:

[image: barplot]

**Edit**

Updated code:

```
import pandas as pd
from io import StringIO
from matplotlib import pyplot

data2 ="""Index     Name        Detection
0   name1           0
1   name2           0
2   name3           0
3   name1           1
4   name3           1
5   name2           1
6   name1           1
7   name1           0"""

df2 = pd.read_csv(StringIO( data2 ), sep='\s+', index_col='Index', engine='python')
result = df2.groupby(by=['Name','Detection']).size().reset_index()
result.rename(columns={0:"count"}, inplace=True)
# plot bar graph
result.set_index(["Name","Detection"])['count'].unstack().plot.bar()
```

Output plot:

[image: newbarplot]

Note that

```
result.set_index(["Name","Detection"])
```

is the dataframe in this form:

```
                 count
Name  Detection       
name1 0              2
      1              2
name2 0              1
      1              1
name3 0              1
      1              1
```

and it is the essence of your question rather than the bar plot of it. The dataframe now has 2 indexes that reveal the `count` values clearly for each paired indexes of (name, detection), more intuitive than the original. The 2-indexes dataframe can be used to created the required bar plot more easily.

You miss to focus on the processing of the dataframe and make people think  that you ask for something that already have good answer.

Comment: Thanks, but I want to plot the count of "Detection" (0's red color and 1's blue color) as y-axsis, based on each name. For example for name1 -->2 (0's) and name1 -->2 (1's)

Comment: @meee You can edit your question to enable reopening it. If you can do appropriately I will vote to open it.

Comment: @meee People who vote to close think that your dataframe is ready to plot such bargraph, and there is already a good answer to your question. In fact it is not ready or not convenient to do so. It needs some manipulation that I demonstrate. The resulting dataframe with paird-indexes is a result, and it is more important than the plot. With that form of dataframe, you need one-liner code to plot what you need.